# Recieving 404 on fetch post request to Spring Rest Controller?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, fetch, spring-rest

I have the following form:

```
<form class="form-leave-room" th:if="${memberService.isAlreadyMemberOf(member, room)}" method="POST">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn--pink" name="roomId"
          th:value="${room.id}">Leave</button>
</form>
```

And I want to submit this form to a Spring RestController via Fetch:

```
let leaveForms = document.querySelectorAll(".form-leave-room");
leaveForms.forEach(form => {
    form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        let newForm = new FormData(form);
        fetch("/membership/api/leaveRoom", {
            method: 'POST',
            body: newForm,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            }
        })
    })
});
```

The RestController is as follows:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/membership/api")
public class PublicRoomsRestController {
    private MemberService memberService;
    private BoredRoomService roomService;

    @Autowired
    public PublicRoomsRestController(MemberService memberService, BoredRoomService roomService) {
        this.memberService = memberService;
        this.roomService = roomService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/leaveRoom")
    public void leaveRoom(@RequestParam("roomId") String id, Principal principal) {
        int intId = Integer.parseInt(id);
        Member member = memberService.getMemberByName(principal.getName());
        BoredRoom room = roomService.getBoredRoomById(intId);
        System.out.println(member.getUsername() + " " + room.getName());
        memberService.leaveRoom(member, room);
    }
```

When I submit the request, I get a 404. This appears to only happen when using Fetch, however, because when I perform a traditional post request with the html like this:

```
<form class="form-leave-room" th:if="${memberService.isAlreadyMemberOf(member, room)}" method="POST" th:action="@{/membership/api/leaveRoom}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn--pink" name="roomId" 
        th:value="${room.id}">Leave</button>
</form>
```

It works fine. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong with my fetch request?

Edit:
Okay, so I checked the network tab in dev tools, and it appears that when I send the post via Fetch, the request body is missing the csrf token. I tried appending it to the `newForm`, along with the roomId contained in the button with `newForm.append()` but I still get a 404. Anyone know what I'm missing here? Here's the request information from the network tab if it helps:

```
**General**:
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/membership/api/leaveRoom
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 404 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
**Response Headers:**
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date: Thu, 26 Aug 2021 00:21:54 GMT
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
**Request Headers:**
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 266
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: JSESSIONID=6762AB1E013929AB1D2AB43EFF086D4B
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:8080/app/rooms/
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36
**Form Data:**
------WebKitFormBoundaryRRC0Q2HAPZZjS6Jn
Content-Disposition: form-data; name: "_csrf"

83c87519-fc55-41da-9ed9-abc9988ccbff
------WebKitFormBoundaryRRC0Q2HAPZZjS6Jn
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="roomId"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryRRC0Q2HAPZZjS6Jn--
```

Comment: Can you open the network tab in the browser and post the actual request it is making that is causing the 404?

Comment: Could it be that you're leaving out the roomId in the request?

Comment: wrong path? i think you want  `@PostMapping("/membership/api/leaveRoom")` instead of `@PostMapping("/leaveRoom")`

Comment: @SamOrozco I think you're correct, I do not see the roomId in the form data with the fetch request. Why isn't this included when I instantiate a new FormData object? Do I need to manually append this?

Comment: do you see an error in the console? your js just add a event listener that will fire letter on submit

Comment: @OniBarolli I'm not sure how `th:value` works but you need to somehow use that value and put it as a query param in your request.

Comment: @OniBarolli I would inspect the request you're making from the browser first to ensure that is what you expect. Then i would next try to hit your backend resource from postman or some tool like that so that is what you're expecting.

Comment: i think your problem is as @SamOrozco said that you can't put a value in a button

you need to put a hidden input
see my working exmaple
https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-river-1dbwm?file=/index.html
https://requestbin.com/r/enibtgslc4ddd/1xEu3zk0cldYlpQ6jfT0OO3cysI

Comment: or you can get the value from the button with js and append it to the form.

Comment: @flaxon Spring prepends the class-level path as a prefix.

Comment: @SamOrozco It gets turned into a regular rendered `value` parameter in the form, and presumably `body: newForm` _should_ take care of that.

Comment: Okay, so I checked the request from the dev tools and I believe the problem is actually that the csrf token that is automatically generated by spring is not being included in the fetch request. Anyone know how to include this?

Comment: A missing CSRF token wouldn't result in a 404.